# Using HTML 5 GeoLocation API to get location time

Tags: html, geolocation

I just came to know that HTML 5 includes GeoLocation API to determine location via Browser.

I want to know whether it is possible to determine user's TimeZone, and local time using this API.

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [W3C specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position), there is a timestamp that the position was last delivered. But it will be delivered without timezone data.

Since you are using Javascript, and running on a client device. You could add some code into the position callback that obtains the timezone data that you're looking for, and the local user's time along with the position data.